Is there a way to resist spells or abilities with an AOE coming from my teammates, or exclude certain beings from the effect?
In my next game I'm playing a fey (specifically a fairy), and I'm worried about things like Turn the Faithless, as I don't know what my teammates are playing, and they could very easily use it forgetting it affects me, as they're relatively new to D&D. Are there any measures I can take to avoid this, or anything they can do to not affect me as well?

I would consider more than the mechanics of something like turn the faithless, if you have a paladin on your team who hates fey enough that they can manifest magical powers then both of you need to seriously consider your relationship. In session zero I would work out why you are hanging around together at the very least.

It depends on the AoE spell/ability, as well as your allies. Have you considered earmuffs?
No catch-alls, but magic might help.
Unfortunately, there is no catch-all that can help you avoid every possible AoE effect. There are magic items and spells that could potentially give you a helping hand in avoiding them, such as the Cloak of Protection which will give you +1 AC and +1 to saving throws. This doesn't avoid the AoE, but it certainly does help.
The paladin keeps hurting my ears though!
Aside from that, it depends on what caused the AoE. To use your specific example, an Oath of the Ancients paladin can't really avoid you when using their channel divinity Turn the Faithless. The ability states:

...each fey or fiend within 30 feet of you that can hear you must make a Wisdom saving throw.

This is very straightforward. It's a sphere AoE with the origin centered on the paladin, meaning that unless the paladin moves 30 feet away from you before using it, or you are able to cover your ears so that you are not able to hear it, you must make the saving throw.
But what about other AoE spells/effects?
It all depends on where the AoE's point of origin is, and whether the person causing it can decide where it is. One example is stated in the question Can the Faerie Fire spell be oriented in a small space to not affect allies?, which tells us that if the caster can decide on a point of origin, then it can usually be nudged in a way that only affects areas your allies are NOT in.
Careful maneuvering is necessary to really take advantage of this though.
Exceptions to these rules:
Evocation Wizards have the ability to Sculpt Spells starting at level 2:

Beginning at 2nd level, you can create pockets of relative safety within the effects of your evocation spells. When you cast an evocation spell that affects other creatures that you can see, you can choose a number of them equal to 1 + the spell's level. The chosen creatures automatically succeed on their saving throws against the spell, and they take no damage if they would normally take half damage on a successful save.

With this, the wizard can decide to make 1 + spell level allies immune to whatever evocation spell they're casting.
Similarly, a Sorcerer can use their Metamagic Careful Spell to protect up to their CHA modifier allies starting at level 3:

When you cast a spell that forces other creatures to make a saving throw, you can protect some of those creatures from the spell’s full force. To do so, you spend 1 sorcery point and choose a number of those creatures up to your Charisma modifier (minimum of one creature). A chosen creature automatically succeeds on its saving throw against the spell.


Sorcerers have careful spell Metamagic which works similar to Sculpt Spells.

Forgot about that one, adding it now!

@Tasi While I appreciate the enthusiasm for my answer, please remember that you should generally wait 24 hours before accepting an answer

Deafen yourself.

A deafened creature can’t hear and automatically fails any ability check that requires hearing.

This is the rules text for the Deafened Condition. The important part here is that you can't hear. In order to be affected by your ally's ability, you must hear them.
The two easiest ways to take care of this are the silence spell and the warding wind spell. Both are second level spells that inflict the deafened condition on creatures inside their area with no saving throw, and between the two most classes that aren't purely martial have access to at least one of them (including Rangers, Bards, Clerics, Druids, Sorcerers, Wizards, Arcane Tricksters, Eldritch Knights, Some Warlocks, Shadow Monks, Dragonmarked Gnomes in Eberron, and Red Robed Adepts in Dragonlance).

I would note that if this is a regular occurrence, it may be worth learning to communicate with your teammates by signs. In any case, it will have interesting (RPG-wise) consequences; for example if your character forgets to look at their teammates as they're caught up in their own duel, and the Wizard uses Dancing Lights to bring their attention back.

They'll learn
Or, they should, anyway.
Even with new players, you can expect that characters (and their players) will learn fairly quickly how to work with each other.
Sure, something like Turn the Faithless might be a challenge, at least once.  Maybe your companion will accidentally turn you one time.  Hopefully they'll learn the first time.
No broad protections, other than situational awareness and common sense
There's no broad protection that's going to protect you from "things like Turn the Faithless", since that could be a pretty broad category.
There's no spell called "protect fey" that somehow protects fey against things that affect fey.  (Although I suppose your DM could create such a spell . . . there's no inherent reason such a spell couldn't exist.)
But situational awareness and common sense will go a long way.  You can use this both in-character and out-of-character.  If you've successfully communicated in-character to your companions that you're fey, it's reasonable to remind another player of that, player to player, especially if they're new.
